# How to get all concatenation of list elements in order in Python?

Tags: python, token, combinations

###### background

I have lists of numbers and symbols like:

```
[1,':',2022,'.','01','.','01']
```

I would like to call a function like `is_date(string)` on every concatenation of the elements in order.

---

###### minimal example

Considering the simple example `[1,2,3]` as input, the expected list of concatenations should be: `['1','12','2','123','23','3']`

I would like not to get `'13'` in the results

So afterwards I could call:

```
for token in list_of_concatenation:
    if is_date(token):
        do something
```

Comment: Please say more about how you derive the "list of concatenations" from the list of numbers and symbols

Comment: These lists are coming from a custom tokenizer like method which pulls numbers and symbols together. The question above targets to solve edge cases of natural texts like '1: 2021 01 01'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double loop, slicing, and string concatenation:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [str(x) for x in l]
[''.join(l2[i:j+1]) for i in range(len(l2)) for j in range(i, len(l2))]
```

output: `['1', '12', '123', '2', '23', '3']`

Answer (score 1):

How about a nested for loop:

```
sample = [1,':',2022,'.','01','.','01']
sample_str = [str(s) for s in sample]

for ix, i in enumerate(sample_str):
    for j in range(ix, len(sample_str)):
        print(''.join(sample_str[ix:j+1]))
```

output:

```
1
1:
1:2022
1:2022.
1:2022.01
1:2022.01.
1:2022.01.01
:
:2022
:2022.
:2022.01
:2022.01.
:2022.01.01
2022
2022.
2022.01
2022.01.
2022.01.01
.
.01
.01.
.01.01
01
01.
01.01
.
.01
01
```

Comment: This nested loop also gives the desired output! thanks

Comment: good, i'm glad :) @mozway gave almost the same answer, but his code is much cleaner - I recommend using his solution.

Comment: The classical loop version would be useful to make a generator. There was an answer about it but it got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are ***not*** looking for the [itertools.powerset() recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes-1) because it ignores the "order":

```
from itertools import  chain, combinations

# source:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)

    # use  range(1, len(s)+1) to avoid empty result -> comment @mozway
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

d = [1,2,3]

print(list(powerset(d)))
```

wich returns tuples as iterator (that I listified):

```
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

You can filter the result to remove the empty tuple and convert tuples to strings using

```
result = [''.join(map(str, tup)) for tup in powerset(d) if tup]
```

print(result)

to get

```
['1', '2', '3', '12', '13', '23', '123']
```

- for a not that efficient solution you could use that to filter down to what you really really want.

Comment: I would not like to get '13'

Comment: @Patrick I initially had the same idea when I realized that it yields to many combinations. One comment though, don't loop to remove the empty elements, just don't generate them. For this you can modify the `powerset` recipe with `range(1, len(s)+1)` ;)

Comment: Thank you for helping with the question!

Comment: @moz good point - but then its a modified version of the powerset ;) hence why I choose not to modify it -> edited in as comment